# Google Apps Scripts - Optimal way to replace text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have tons of strings that I need to replace in a Google document. My performance to run my script is taking a huge hit and takes forever to run now. I am looking at how to optimize.

```
body.replaceText("oldvalue1",newValue1)
body.replaceText("oldvalue2",newValue2)
body.replaceText("oldvalue3",newValue3)
..
..
..
```

Is there a more optimal way to replace text in a Google Doc using google scripts?

Comment: Obvious doing it in a loop but we need more information to accomplish this.  Please provide [mcve] or try putting oldvalue and newvalue into an array of objects and the use forEach to loop through

Comment: Yes it's possible, called batch update https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate

Comment: I know we can do loops and what not, I am more of trying to do something along the lines of what @Kos is recommending. I feel it is very "expensive" to continually call replaceText on a document. I want to minimize the API calls / optimize performance

Comment: @Kos I am not too familiar with REST api handling. Is there a way to batch update directly from google apps script?

Comment: When you want to achieve your goal using Google Docs API, you can do this using [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). In this case, you can create the script using Google Apps Script. Is the use of Googe Docs API included in the direction of your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Kos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555121/kos) refers in the comments, the best approximation is using Google Docs API [batchUpdates](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate?authuser=0) as [Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) inside Google Apps Script.

I leave you an example on how Docs API works as an Advanced Service. For the example I suppose you have an array of objects that contains the `oldValue` and `newValue`:

```
function batchUpdating(DocID = DocID) {
  const replaceRules = [
    {
      toReplace: "oldValue1",
      newValue: "newValue1"
    },
...
  ]
  const requestBuild = replaceRules.map(rule => {
    var replaceAllTextRequest = Docs.newReplaceAllTextRequest()
    replaceAllTextRequest.replaceText = rule.newValue
    replaceAllTextRequest.containsText = Docs.newSubstringMatchCriteria()
    replaceAllTextRequest.containsText.text = rule.toReplace
    replaceAllTextRequest.containsText.matchCase = false
    Logger.log(replaceAllTextRequest)
    var request = Docs.newRequest()
    request.replaceAllText = replaceAllTextRequest
    return request
  })
  var batchUpdateRequest = Docs.newBatchUpdateDocumentRequest()
  batchUpdateRequest.requests = requestBuild
  var result = Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(batchUpdateRequest, DocID)
  Logger.log(result)
}
```

Google Apps Script helps us handle the authorization flow, and gives us hints on how to construct our request. For example, `Docs.newReplaceAllTextRequest()`, helps us build the request for that service, giving us hints that it contains `replaceText` and `containText`. In any case, we could also supply the object directly to the request:

```js
const requestBuild = replaceRules.map(rule => {
    return {
      replaceAllText:
      {
        replaceText: rule.newValue,
        containsText: { text: rule.oldValue, matchCase: false }
      }
    }
})
```

###### To take in account

> Each request is validated before being applied. If any request is not valid, then the entire request will fail and nothing will be applied.

> If your script project uses a default GCP project created on or after April 8, 2019, the API is enabled automatically after you enable the advanced service and save the script project. If you have not done so already, you may also be asked to agree to the Google Cloud Platform and Google APIs Terms of Service as well.

###### Documentation:

- [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request?authuser=0#replacealltextrequest)
- [SubstringMatchCriteria](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request?authuser=0#substringmatchcriteria)

Comment: Thank you for this. After testing batch updates vs just replaceText over and over I actually found the batch updates method to take longer. Not sure why. For now I am going to stick with replaceText manually for every piece of text.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.forEach(obj => { body.replaceText(obj.old,obj.new)})
```

@kos way is probably a better way to go.